How to apply CSS to Google Category filters
I been trying to customize & apply CSS to Google Category filters
My Filter code


   var reg_filter = new google.visualization.ControlWrapper({      
            controlType: 'CategoryFilter',
            containerId: 'filter_div',
            dataTable: x_columnTable,
            options: {
              filterColumnLabel: 'State',
              ui: {
                labelStacking: 'horizontal',
                allowTyping: false,
                allowMultiple: true,
                //selectedValuesLayout:'belowWrapping'
                }
              },
              // Define an initial state, i.e. a set of metrics to be initially selected.
              state: initState
        });
          .label_{
              font-size:18px;
              font-weight:normal;
              font-family:"Condensed-Regular";  
              letter-spacing: -0.2px;
              color: #005596;
            }
           .filter_cont{
             display:flex;
             width:300px;
             height:50px;
             margin:auto;    
            }
        
         .chart_container1{
          display:flex;
          float:left;
          width:600px;
          height:500px;
          margin:auto;    
        }
My CSS for Label & Drop Down
        <label class="label_"> Select </label> <br> 
        <div id="filter" class="filter_cont"></div>     
        <div id="chart_pdiv" class="chart_container1"></div>




I have three questions related to it

How do I apply CSS to Label?
How do I apply CSS to dropdown - change width, height & Font type?
How do I Hide selectedValuesLayout?


I gone through Google Chart documentation it was mentioned to use ui.CssClass, but how can I implement it here?
I want to make Allow multiple values true for the filter and same time I want to hide selectedValuesLayout, becasue my catogory filter will have more than 10 values
Below is the part I am trying to hide

It would be great if someone helps with an working snippet.

To apply css to the label you can use the ui.label option to customize the label's appearance using a CSS class,
and for the drop down width, height, and font type, use an external css targeting the generated dom element,
and for the selectedValuesLayout , since there is no function to disable it directly through google API , you can also target the created element and hide it
This is a snippet of the fix
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      google.charts.load('current', { packages: ['corechart', 'controls'] });
      google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawDashboard);

      function drawDashboard() {
        var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
          ['State', 'Population'],
          ['California', 38332521],
          ['Texas', 26448193],
          ['New York', 19651127],
          ['Florida', 19552860],
          ['Illinois', 12882135],
          ['Pennsylvania', 12773801]
        ]);

        var reg_filter = new google.visualization.ControlWrapper({
          controlType: 'CategoryFilter',
          containerId: 'filter_div',
          options: {
            filterColumnLabel: 'State',
            ui: {
              labelStacking: 'horizontal',
              allowTyping: false,
              allowMultiple: true,
              cssClass: 'custom-category-filter'
            }
          }
        });

        var chart = new google.visualization.ChartWrapper({
          chartType: 'PieChart',
          containerId: 'chart_div',
          options: {
            width: 600,
            height: 400,
            legend: 'right'
          }
        });

        var dashboard = new google.visualization.Dashboard(
          document.getElementById('dashboard_div')
        );

        dashboard.bind(reg_filter, chart);
        dashboard.draw(data);
      }
    </script>

    <style>
      /* Style for the label */
      .label_ {
        font-size: 18px;
        font-weight: normal;
        font-family: "Condensed-Regular";
        letter-spacing: -0.2px;
        color: #005596;
      }

      /* Style for the dropdown */
      .custom-category-filter select {
        width: 200px;
        height: 30px;
        font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
        font-size: 16px;
      }

      /* More specific class to hide only the selected values section */
      .custom-category-filter .goog-inline-block .goog-menuitem {
        display: none !important;
      }

      .chart_container1 {
        display: flex;
        float: left;
        width: 600px;
        height: 500px;
        margin: auto;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <label class="label_">Select</label> <br>
    <div id="dashboard_div">
      <div id="filter_div" class="filter_cont"></div>
      <div id="chart_div" class="chart_container1"></div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>


Thank you will check and accept the Answer

Alright , let me know how it goes

State Filter seems not working in the code Snippet

/* Hide the selected values section */
.custom-category-filter .goog-inline-block {
display: none !important;
} This code disables the filter, any suggestion's?

Yeah , it because the .goog-inline-block is also affecting other parts of the Google Category Filter
The best option is to use more specific class. I update the code with a better fix

Thanks for helping me, would you mind looking this fiddle, seems fix is also not working as expected. https://jsfiddle.net/Tpkakilan/bp14c6Lw/22/
